# In ggplot how do I connect geom_points to create a election slope graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

To visualise the 2017 results and compare it with 2015, I want to create a slope graph of the UK election results. Now, I created a scatter plot, but can't seem to figure out how to connect the dots.

**Here's the data frame:**

```
   parties year seats
1      CON 2015   331
2      CON 2017   318
3      LAB 2015   232
4      LAB 2017   261
5      SNP 2015    56
6      SNP 2017    35
7       LD 2015     8
8       LD 2017    12
9      DUP 2015     8
10     DUP 2017    10
11  Others 2015    15
12  Others 2017    13

df2$year <- as.factor(df2$year)
```

**In this ggplot code creates only the dots:**

```
ggplot(df2, aes(year, seats, colour = parties)) +
  geom_point()
```

Result:

[Rplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPyvZ.png)

Comment: you need to set `group = parties` and also use `geom_line`

Comment: Great thanks @amatsuo_ne